# Tokenization of sentence final punctuations when they are not followed by whitespace

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

We are trying to select a tokenizer to utilize in our annotation pipeline. Currently, I am testing the PTBTokenizer with some twitter texts.
In our data we have some texts in which there is no whitespace after the sentence final dot:"This is a test.And some more."
The PTBTokenizer does not recognize "test",".","And" as separate tokens, instead it takes the "test.And"as a single token. Is there any option or setting in the tokenizer which makes it to recognize the sentence final punctuations as single tokens even though it is not followed by a white space?

Thank you.

Comment: what about adding a white space yourself after every dot ?

Comment: Not all dots are final punctuations. Such as the ones in "e.g., U.S., Corp., http://xxx.yy" etc. So, this is a real NLP problem which requires some effort to solve. That's why I didn't insert space around dots. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not all dots are final punctuations. Such as "e.g., U.S., Corp."   etc. So, this is a real NLP problem which requires some effort to solve. That's why I didn't insert space around dots.
Thanks.